# Memcpy issue in 64 bit compiler

Tags: c

For starters my main objective is to convert unsigned long to unsigned int in 64 bit environment (and do it without any compilation warnings).  This can be easily done with this function:

```
unsigned int a_to_b(unsigned long a)
{
     return((unsigned int)(a));
}
```

Although it gives correct result but problem with this is that in 64 bit environment it throws warning at compile time :

> 1506-742 (I) 64-bit portability: possible loss of digits through conversion of unsigned long int type into unsigned int type.

To bypass this warning we tried this function:

```
unsigned int a_to_b(unsigned long a)
{
    unsigned int b;
    int skip = sizeof(unsigned long) - sizeof(unsigned int);
    memcpy(&b, (&a)+skip, sizeof(b));
    return(b);
}
```

Now this doesn't give any warning at compile time but it doesn't give correct output. 
I tried this same code in 32 bit compiler and it works fine.

Please suggest how to correct this behavior of memcpy or any other way to bypass warning.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that a `long` could be longer than an `int`?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  A warning on `return a;` wouldn't surprise me, but I'd be surprised to see a warning with an explicit case like `return (unsigned int)a;`.  A cast says to the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing."

Comment: do you know that you can suppress compiler warning with `#pragma`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440614/disable-warning-in-msvc2010

Comment: I'm amazed at how everyone is missing the obvious XY problem here. :)

Comment: On Windows long is 32 bits but in most other Linux/Unix environments long is 64 bits

Comment: What do you want the program to do if it gets passed a value of A that is greater than UINT_32_MAX ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response (somehow i didn't get e-mail notifications so could not respond earlier).

Comment: Mystical : yes long is 8 byte in 64 bit compiler which i am using and int is 4 byte. But my source will always be within 4 bytes.( I am migrating from 32 bit to 64 bit ).

Comment: ADAM : Compiler is IBM XL C .
Ian : It's not going to pass the value at least in the scenarios which i am working on . And if it does then it will involve re writing some more code , which i hope would be simpler as i can remove the typecasting problem at the source.

Comment: And another problem when i tried for some alternate solution:

Comment: void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   unsigned long ul =465287295;
   void *ptr_int;
   unsigned int *ptr1;
   ptr_int =&ul;
   ptr1=ptr_int;
   printf(" Variable address %d, Value  : %d First pointer address %d\n",&ul,ul,ptr_int);
   printf(" New pointer address %d , new value afterssignment %d\n", ptr1,*ptr1);
   }  

This should give same value but the address from both pointer is same (-4736) and the value is 465287295(original) and 0 from int pointer

Comment: `void main()` is unconditionally wrong on Unix and AIX.  You get 0 from the `int *` because 465287295 is 0x1BBBB87F (a 32-bit value) and on big-endian machines such as those which run AIX, the high-order 4-bytes (which are all zero for the value shown) are stored before the low-order 4 bytes.

Comment: Used Int main() but same issue . I am using a normal digit there should be no issue regarding the size of the datatypes in above pointer example but it is refusing to give correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int a_to_b(unsigned long a)
{
     return(a & UINT_MAX);
}
```

That passes on Mac OS X 10.9.4 with GCC 4.9.1 set to very fussy:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c cvt.c
```

I can't test on AIX (or is it HP-UX?).

---

As noted in a comment:

> I really don't like the idea, but one possibility is:
>
> ```
> union
> {
>     unsigned long ul;
>     unsigned int ui[2];
> } u;
> ```
>
> and assign the argument to `u.ul` and return either `u.ui[0]` or `u.ui[1]` (probably the latter since AIX runs on Power chips which are big-endian, at least by default). It's a cheat. The compiler might be good enough to spot the 'misuse', but probably won't.

Fleshed out into semi-portable code:

```
unsigned int a_to_b(unsigned long a)
{
    const unsigned long byteorder = 0xFF;
    const int LOW_ORDER_4_BYTES = (*(char *)&byteorder == 0); 
    union
    {
        unsigned long ul;
        unsigned int  ui[2];
    } u;
    u.ul = a;
    return(u.ui[LOW_ORDER_4_BYTES]);
}
```

Tested on a little-endian machine, it gives the correct result.  I think it should automatically detect big-endian machines and give the correct result there, but I've not been able to verify that.

Complete test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int a_to_b(unsigned long a);

unsigned int a_to_b(unsigned long a)
{
    const unsigned long byteorder = 0xFF;
    const int LOW_ORDER_4_BYTES = (*(char *)&byteorder == 0); 
    union
    {
        unsigned long ul;
        unsigned int ui[2];
    } u;
    u.ul = a;
    return(u.ui[LOW_ORDER_4_BYTES]);
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long x = 0xFEDCBA9876543210ULL;
    printf("0x%.8X\n", a_to_b(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x76543210
```

Comment: It's AIX , 
this works  but it gives the same warning during compilation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not dreadfully surprised.  There probably isn't a way to suppress that warning on AIX, then, though you could try looking at the compiler documentation to see whether there's anything else you can do.  I really don't like the idea, but one possibility is `union { unsigned long ul; unsigned int ui[2]; } u;` and assign the argument to `u.ul` and return either `u.ui[0]` or `u.ui[1]` (probably the latter since AIX runs on Power chips which are big-endian, at least by default).  It's a cheat.  The compiler might be good enough to spot the 'misuse', but probably won't.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't do like this, May cause trap representation in specific machine.*

you computer is little endian. You should write like this:

```
unsigned int a_to_b(unsigned long a)
{
    unsigned int b;
    memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));
    return(b);
}
```

[Big and Little Endian](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html)

Comment: You really should never use memcpy to cast from one type to another. That is really really UB!

Comment: I tried this too in my hit and trial time and it was not working.

Comment: AIX runs on big-endian machines, not little-endian machines (at least, by default, the Power chips where AIX runs are big-endian).

Comment: @IanNorton Using `memcpy` is the safest way to implement type-punning. It is not undefined behavior, much less “really really UB”. It gives implementation-defined results, obviously.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: In theory, using `memcpy` could result in your writing a trap representation to the destination, if the architecture has trap representations (C99 §6.2.6.2).  I'm not aware, however, of any modern architectures in current usage which have trap representations for unsigned integer types (or any integer types for that matter).